# How to use Ubuntu Lucid Server as SVN/Trac server

Tags: ubuntu, trac, ubuntu-10.04, svn

Does anyone know of a tutorial for setting up Trac and SVN on a Ubuntu 10.4 Server machine?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [chapter on installing Subversion](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/subversion.html) on Ubuntu 10.04 in the official Server Guide. For Trac you can probably just install the official [trac package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/trac) and follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: I followed the tutorial for installing the SVN server and I have it running (I think) but how do I import/commit/checkout?  The main problem is that I don't know the URL to commit/import/checkout to/from.

Comment: The section "Access Methods" describes several ways to access your Subversion repositories. The URL to your repository depends on the mechanism you are using (`svn://`, `svn+ssh://`, `https://`...) but most likely includes the hostname of your server and a path to your repo. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Notes on setup for trac should be in /usr/share/doc/trac after package install.  These generally detail configuration that is not automatically done during installation.  First file to check is README.Debian or README.Debian.gz.  Use less or zless to look at them.

Trac should pull in subversion.  If not, install the subversion pacakge.  Documentation will be in /usr/share/doc/subversion.